# Finding Primes with Modulo in Python

Tags: python, lambda, primes, modulus, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have been sweating over this piece of code -- which returns all the primes in a list:

```
primes = range(2, 20) 
for i in range(2, 8): 
     primes = filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, primes)

print primes
```

It works... but I don't understand the role "`x == i or x % i`" plays in the whole thing.

I also don't understand why the second range is only 2 to 7.

I even created a Python implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes, hoping that might give me some insight, but it didn't.

When I remove the `x % i` component, I would expect this code to give me the numbers common to both sets, but it does not:

```
nums = [2, 20] 
for i in range(2, 8): 
     nums = filter(lambda x: x == i, nums)

print nums
```

Why is this?

Likewise, when I remove the `x == i` component, it returns the prime numbers from 11 to 19.

```
nums = range(2, 20) 

for i in range(2, 8): 
     nums = filter(lambda x: x % i, nums)

print nums
```

Again, I don't understand why it ignores all primes below 11.

Next, I tried this:

```
nums = [13] 

for i in range(2, 8): 
     nums = filter(lambda x: x % i, nums)

print nums
```

Again, this makes no sense to me. The lambda is iterating over `x` in `nums` correct? And `i` is iterating over the range 2 to 7. So, aren't we taking `13 % i`... for 2 to 7? How does that result in "13"?

Using the same logic as immediately above, I did the same thing with "13", but using `x == i` in the lambda.

```
for i in range(2, 8): 
     nums = filter(lambda x: x == i, nums)

print nums
```

And as I expected, it returned an empty list -- which makes sense in my mind, because 13 never appears in the range of 2 to 7.

For reference to anyone trying to help, this is the mindset I'm in when I work with `filter()` and lambdas:

```
a = range (1, 11)
b = range (9, 20) 

for i in filter(lambda x: x in a, b):
    print i,
```

This, of course, gives us "9 10". I know the structure of the loop is different, but hopefully it will help you see where my confusion lies.

I have worked with `filter()` and lambdas somewhat extensively, so I thought I could figure it out, but I'm stumped! I just hope the answer isn't so blindingly obvious that I feel like an idiot...

Comment: Where did you get that original snippet from? It's pretty bad. I would _not_ look to it as an example of how to find the prime numbers in a list.

Comment: I ran across it on Stack Overflow somewhere. I just want to find out how it works.

Comment: `x == i or x % i` is the same as saying `x % i == 0 and x != i`. When `x == i`, `x % i` will never be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a compact (but somewhat obscure) implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes [EDIT: as pointed out in the comments, this is in fact an "unfaithful sieve" as the trial division causes [worse time complexity](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) than the actual Sieve of Eratosthenes].

The first line is just an arbitrary search range of consecutive integers to filter for primes:

```
primes = range(2, 20)
```

Next, [following the sieve algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), we  iterate with integer i in range (2, n) where n is naively the largest number in the search range (though in this case, 7 is the chosen upper bound -- more on this below).

```
for i in range(2, 8): 
    primes = filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, primes)
```

The algorithm states that we **include i** and exclude **multiples of i**. That's what the lambda predicates filter for --

- include i: `x == 1`
- exclude multiples of i: `x % i` -- this is short hand for `x % i != 0`. In other words, x is not divisible by i, or alternatively, x is not a multiple of i.

The upper bound of 8 seems somewhat arbitrary -- minimally, we only need to search up to `sqrt(n)`, since `sqrt(n) * sqrt(n) = n` means that `sqrt(n)` is an upper bound on the search space.

The square root of 19 is approximately 4.4, and in this example you see that the list of primes does not change after i = 3.

```
In [18]: primes = range(2, 20)

In [19]: for i in range(2, 8):
   ....:     primes = filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, primes)
   ....:     print i, primes
   ....:
2 [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
3 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
4 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
5 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
6 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
7 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

Comment: Also, the `range` function is not inclusive. It's only searching up to `19`.

Comment: not of Eratosthenes though, but the sieve by trial division. sieve of Eratosthenes doesn't test for divisibility at all, it just enumerates multiples of each found prime, by addition in constant steps, so it generates the composites by itself, without testing. That's what special about it.

Comment: @WillNess, indeed, the time complexity in question is different... I shall edit my post.

Answer (score 3):

The first code block you posted is the easiest example for me to explain this:

```py
primes = range(2, 20) 
for i in range(2, 8): 
    primes = filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, primes)
print primes
```

When using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) method, the important thing to note is that you only have to remove numbers that are products of numbers **up to the square root of the max**. The use of `range(2,8)` above implements this (it goes from 2 to 7, which is further than necessary). The square root of 19 (the highest number in the outer range that is checked) is between 4 and 5. So the highest number that should be checked in the range is 4 (we only need to check integers).

Using this knowledge, you could improve the code to be as follows (this finds primes <= 19):

```py
import math
max = 19    #Set it here
max += 1
primes = range(2, max) 
for i in range(2, int( math.ceil(math.sqrt(max)) )): 
    primes = filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, primes)
print primes
```

Note that instead of using `floor` and then adding one because `range` is exclusive, I use `ceil`.

Run it here: http://repl.it/8N8

Edit: I also realized this (and the code provided in the question) isn't a complete implementation of the sieve method, since according to the algorithm, we should only flag multiples of *primes*, meaning that the inner use of `range` is not as efficient as it should be.

See a graphical illustration of the algorithm in progress:

[image: Sieve of Eratosthenes]

Comment: an obligatory clarification of the OP code [*not* being the sieve of *Eratosthenes*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990094/finding-primes-with-modulo-in-python#comment44393470_27991297). The included picture shows why: on step 1 it marks the 2 and its multiples and starts from 3 on the next step (working on the same original list); whereas the OP code passes through the 2 and all the numbers that are *not* multiples of 2, on step 1, and then repeats from 2 again (with fewer remaining numbers in the list) on the next step. SoE marks 45 *twice*; OP's would remove it *once* (if up to 100).

Comment: Yeah. The important thing to note is that there is a trade-off. You can either start with a list and *remove* numbers, or you can *flag* numbers (which is what SoT does). If I was programming to be efficient, in both performance and memory, I would encode the flags with each flag represented by a single bit in memory (8 per byte). I would set flags by ANDing the byte with another one. At the end, then you just count which bits are still set.

Comment: right. (correction: "(which is what *SoE* does)".) or your language could have BitSets (like Java), or bit-packed Boolean vectors (like C++'s `vector<bool>`).

Comment: OK, that was so subtle I missed it completely, and it fixes both of my objections. I'll remove my comment.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a simple list comprehension to generate prime numbers. Of course the core idea was copied in stack overflow. To be honest it took time for me to understand it as I was beginner in python. I have used this list comprehension by 
calling a lambda function separately. So first I will discuss the lambda function.

*lambda function:* 
is_prime = lambda x: all(x % y != 0 for y in range(2,int(math.sqrt(x)) + 1))

Now the list comprehension using the above lambda.

primes = [x for x in range(30) if is_prime(x) == True]

Comment: You lambda function returns True for is_prime (1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ip_list = [100, 200, 300, 17, 19, 23, 21]

is_prime = list(filter(lambda i: all(i%j!=0 for j in range(2, i//2)), ip_list))

print(is_prime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Code for getting prime number from 2 - 100

`Code :`

```
l=list(filter(lambda x: not list(filter(lambda y : x%y==0, range(2,x))),range(2,100)))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is fairly simple.  Increase your set of primes from range(2,20) to range(2,30) and try your thought experiment again.  It will me much more obvious.

the filter function will return values for the range of range(2,20) that the

```
filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, primes)
```

returns true.

In addition to increasing the primes from range(2,20) to range(2,30), play with your inner filter criteria and you will start to see the differences you are looking for.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

primes = range(2, 30) 
for i in range(2, 3): 
    primes = filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, primes)

print primes
```

which results in:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29]
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/python

primes = range(2, 30) 
for i in range(2, 4): 
    primes = filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, primes)

print primes
```

results in

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29]
```

Answer (score -2):

This code snippet will print prime numbers from 1 to 15:

```py
lst = filter(lambda x: len(list(filter(lambda n: x % n != 0, range(2, x)))) == x - 2, range(15))
print (list(lst))
```

Comment: In programming, you should rarely use a one-liner such as the one above. By so much unnecessary nesting, you decrease the readability of the code. It is also best to not just give a code answer on SO. Try and write something with it to explain what you have done and why it works.

Comment: The question is not "how do I print prime numbers", so this is not answering the question at all.